# definite article 'a'

Tags: grammar, articles, compound-adjectives

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, pag 529, says:

> Predeterminer AdjPs (e.g., ***such*** a nuisance, or ***so serious*** a problem) occur as
>        external modiﬁer in NP structure, preceding the definite article *a*.

I'd like to know whether there's a typo, and it should read "indefinite article *a*", or rather it's a definite sense of such an article.

Comment: Yes, it's an error. I'll advise the authors.

Comment: @BillJ How can you assure so?

Comment: Because of the examples they give: "such **a** nuisance" / "so serious **a** problem".

Comment: @BillJ's right. It's obviously a typo. A book that big probably contains others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Geoff Pullum, coauthor of CGEL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Tea_room/2018/October#definite_article_a):

"You seem to be exactly right: it’s a plangent error, “definite” for “indefinite”. Lots of odd things happen in English NP syntax, but use of “a” as a definite article is not one of them!"